# Why can't my code access this variable?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, requirejs

I'm trying to build an extension for another program using an SDK. The code is written in JavaScript.

I am loading in an external library (Highcharts) using the SDK's built-in requireJS functionality.

However when I try to access Highcharts, via the Highcharts variable, the browser tells me it is undefined.

I tried console.log(this) to my code, after it should have been loaded, and you can see the output below, in the image. Highcharts seems to have been loaded. When I try console.log(EPCMPROXY) I get that object, but when I try console.log(Highcharts), I get undefined. If I open the console of the browser window, and manually type in Highcharts, it returns the object. Am I doing something wrong, or referencing Highcharts incorrectly? How is it possible that I can access the one object (EPCMPROXY) but not the other (Highcharts) when they are in the same scope?

Code:

```
console.log(this);
console.log(Highcharts);
console.log(EPCMPROXY);  //some var generated by the page, used as example here
```

Output of console.log(this):

```
j {owner: f, init: function, componentDeleted: function, beforeUpdate: function, afterUpdate: function…}
    $:function ()
        arguments : null
        caller : null
        length : 0
        name : ""
        prototype : Object
        __proto__ : function ()
        [[FunctionLocation]] : combined_static_includes_1.jsversion=20170105152024:25
        [[Scopes]]:Scopes[2]
            0 : Closure (a)
            1 : Global
                $ : function (e,i)
                AsyncHandleJavascriptError : function AsyncHandleJavascriptError(a)
                EPCMPROXY : Object
                ES6Promise : Object
                Highcharts : Object
```

Output of console.log(Highcharts):

```
undefined
```

Output of console.log(EPCMPROXY):

```
Object
  ...
```

[image: Console Screenshot]

Comment: Can we a [mcve] of the code?

Comment: If you are using RequireJS, I would expect that you would want to load highcharts as a module.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've added the code, but I don't think the code is the point here. The point is how can I reference Highcharts correctly, when it is clearly there (but it doesn't seem to be working for me).

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not directly using requireJS. It is being used in the background by the SDK. I't just telling it what libraries to import. The question is more about: How is it possible that I can see the Highcharts object when I check this (console.log(this)), but I get 'undefined' when I try to access it.

Comment: Hightcharts, as shown in that screenshot is not available globally. It is being displayed by the debugger/console but is actually inside of the closure you are printing.

Comment: *"How is it possible that I can see the Highcharts object when I check this (console.log(this)), but I get 'undefined' when I try to access it."* It is easily possible in async world. But you don't give enough details to answer more specifically.

Comment: But then how can I access EPCMPROXY (the object listed right above Highcharts)?

Comment: @dfsq So you're saying that console.log(this) could show me objects that weren't actually available / defined at that time?

Comment: Of course. Hover over blue "i" icon and read what it says.

Comment: @dfsq Thank you for pointing that out. I hadn't realized that. I guess it just hasn't finished loading that library then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the line "console.log(Highcharts)" is executed, it wasn't actually loaded yet (due to problems with my requireJS set-up). The reason I could see it when I executed "console.log(this)" is, as dsfq pointed out, that it shows objects that might have been loaded later, since it is run asynchronously. The little blue "i" icon, which can be seen in the screenshot, is actually a tooltip from Chrome which states: "Value below was evaluated just now".